# HTML Element "properties" in dev tools?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, onscroll

I'm attempting to add an onScroll event listener that fetches data upon hitting the bottom.  As such, I'm trying to figure out where in the "event" object I can access info about where I am in the scroll height.  My "pokeList" element has `overflow-y: scroll` but the element does not have any properties in Chrome dev tools (where as pretty much every other site I visit has properties associated with each HTML element).  Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Image below.  Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0eSQ.png)

Comment: Random idea, are you sure your page isn't *blocking* while you're looking at the devtools (like in a `prompt` or `alert`)? That may cause some failures

Comment: show actual code

Comment: @DCR what would you like to see big guy

Comment: @CertainPerformance hmm i don't have any alerts or prompts in my code, but i appreciate the thought and input.  anything else that would be blocking?